# Force reset system preferences cache

Tags: terminal, script, system-settings, plist

I'm trying to enable/disable time announcement feature that's present in *Dock & Menu Bar > Clock > Announce the time* with a shell script.

[image: system preference window]

When I read the plist file, I can see that it's set to 0.

```bash
> defaults read com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs
{
    TimeAnnouncementPrefs =     {
        TimeAnnouncementsEnabled = 0;
        TimeAnnouncementsIntervalIdentifier = EveryQuarterHourInterval;
        TimeAnnouncementsPhraseIdentifier = ShortTime;
        TimeAnnouncementsVoiceSettings =         {
            CustomVolume = "0.5";
            VoiceIdentifier = "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.samantha.compact";
        };
    };
}
```

Then I can enable it with:

```bash
> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :TimeAnnouncementPrefs:TimeAnnouncementsEnabled 1" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs.plist
> defaults read com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs
```

which turns on the feature without a problem.

When I set it to `0` to disable it, it changes the plist file, and the system preferences app shows it disabled (grayed out). But it continues announcing the time. I have to manually go to settings and turn the feature on & off to get it to apply.

These are the commands I used:

#### Approach 1: using PlistBuddy

```
> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :TimeAnnouncementPrefs:TimeAnnouncementsEnabled 0" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs.plist
> defaults read com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs
```

#### Approach 2: using defaults

I also tried writing the whole dictionary at once using just `defaults`

```
defaults write com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs '{TimeAnnouncementPrefs={TimeAnnouncementsEnabled=1;TimeAnnouncementsIntervalIdentifier=EveryQuarterHourInterval;TimeAnnouncementsVoiceSettings={CustomVolume="0.5";VoiceIdentifier="com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.samantha.compact";};};}'
```

#### Approach 3: replacing the file

I also tried replacing the whole file with the copies I made of both states (`enabled.plist` and `disabled.plist`) and calling `defaults read com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs`

All these approaches change the setting. When I quit and reopen preferences app, I can see that it's disabled. However it doesn't take effect.

---

I tried running all of these to force it to reload but it didn't help.

```
> defaults read com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs
> killall cfprefsd
> defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs.plist
```

How can I get System Preferences to load the settings from plist files and apply them?

I'm running macOS Big Sur 11.4 (20F71)

Comment: Can you show us the shell script that sets it? If you're using defaults write, then that should update the cache.

Comment: @benwiggy I added the commands I tried in the post.

Comment: I've tried all this as well, macOS 12. plist values are obnoxiously sticky and make software development really hard to test. Even killing cfprefsd doesn't work... what is going on ?! My only solution has been a hard machine restart

Comment: For what it's worth, I solved this problem by running `say` via a cronjob